# How to change the convolution fliter in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I know there are some ways to use specific convolution fliter like dilated convolution by using the op `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d`.But if I want to realize the structure like [Convolution in Convolution for Network in Network.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06759v1.pdf),how can I change the fliter of the op like`tf.nn.conv2d`.

Is writing a brand new op the only way to achieve that?
Or if I would like to use data transformation to realize it, will the automatic differentiation work? Is there any document to use data transformation?

Comment: Define the transformation you want to achieve. `atrous+conv2d` is achieved using conv2d.

Comment: @vijay-m That's a good news for me,thanks.